# Javascript - filtering data with text input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create filtering function where user can start typing text in the input box and the function will show/hide data as the user is typing. Also it needs to combine two or more words, but only to show the results which have that combination of words, and not to show data where the words can be found (as the function is working at the moment). I am trying to create this some time and I am out of ideas what to do.

This is the last working code ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/911hx0bd/4/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-search">
    <input type="text" name="input-filter" class=form-control id="input-filter" placeholder="Search Here">
</div>
<div>  
    <a class="gallery"  data-tags="chaos board nordic viking warriors display ship dock warhammer fantasy"></a>
    <a class="gallery" data-tags="modular necron obelisk pyramid ziggurat scenery gaming board wasteland warhammer 40k"></a>
    <a class="gallery" data-tags="modular nurgle imperial chaos gaming board toxic crossroad warhammer 40k"></a>
    <a class="gallery" data-tags="modular necron obelisk pyramid ziggurat scenery warhammer 40k"></a>
    <a class="gallery" data-tags="ork orc fort fortress modular palisade wood skaven scenery warhammer fantasy"></a>   
</div>
```

JS:

```
var inputFilter = $('#input-filter');
inputFilter.on('keyup', function() {

            var
                $this  = $(this),
                search = $this.val().toLowerCase(),
                words = search.split(/\s+/),
                data;

                if(search.length > 2){
                    $('.gallery').hide();
                    $('a[data-tags]').filter(function(){
                       // splitting the data-tags attribute to an array of words:
                       data = this.dataset.tags.split(/\s+/);

                       // looking to see if any of the words (from the value)
                       // are present in the array formed from the data-tags
                       // attribute, using Array.prototype.some() to iterate
                       // over the given array, returning a Boolean true or false:
                       return words.some(function (word) {
                           return data.indexOf(word) > -1;
                       });
                   }).show();
                }

                if(search == ''){
                    $('.gallery').show();
                }

        });
```

Comment: so whats you're actual question?

Comment: Why not just use a library for this? I believe you are re-inventing the wheel here and while some of your implementation may be made to work it is probably not going to be as efficient as a long standing open source project.

Comment: @indubitablee - The search only does OR and not AND.

Comment: i understand u correct? when you type 2 words you want only elements having both words in the list?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, and at the moment that is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return  words.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
                    return previousValue &&  data.indexOf(currentValue) > -1;
                     },true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/911hx0bd/5/

the true at the end is the init value which is the previousValue of the first value in the array

Comment: This is working, but there is still an issue when **space** character is entered - this list becomes hidden. I will try to find fix for this.

Comment: change  words=search.split(/\s+/)  to words = search.match(/\S+/g), to match the non-whitespace